# Windows Server 2012 unable to access specific SSL page

Tags: networking, ssl, firewall, https

This problem really boggles the mind. 
I have a standard Windows 2012 server with windows firewall enabled.

Using Chrome, I am unable to access a certain HTTPS website while other HTTPS websites can be accessed without problems. Error: Time out.

Cannot access: "https://www.onlinepayment.com.my/MOLPay/"
Can access: google.com, paypal.com

Onlinepayment.com.my is accessible from home/office PC without issue.
From the server, I can ping to Onlinepayment.com.my.

I have tried allowing 443 port, disabled the firewall, use different browser (IE) and it all doesn't open the page.

I have tried asking the hosting company if they have a firewall in between, they said nope.

Comment: Addition: The reason why I need to access that specific page is because there is an API call I need to call from my server.
After continously getting TimeOut error, I tried to access through Chrome only to find out the problem above :(

Answer (score 2):

This is years late... but for those who run into issues with SSL certificates. There are a couple tests you can run which will give insight to what your issue might be.

**Testing SSL Installations Using Bash:**

- Try to establish a connection with OpenSSL:

  ```
  openssl s_client -connect www.onlinepayment.com.my:443
  ```
- Test for redirects that may have a CN or SAN that doesnt match the certificate:

  ```
  curl -I -L https://www.onlinepayment.com.my/MOLPay/
  ```

**Testing SSL Installations Using Windows:**

- Per [this stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47533798/how-to-show-tls-handshake-information-and-connect-request-in-invoke-webrequest), you can establish a connection to the server using powershell and get some information:

  ```
  $response = Invoke-WebRequest -uri "https://www.onlinepayment.com.my/MOLPay/"
  $response.BaseResponse
  $response.RawContent.Split("`n")[0..20]
  ```
- Digicert has a [free application](https://www.digicert.com/util/) for windows which can scan internal or external sites to check the installed certificate. Run the exe and go to `Tools > Check Install`.

**Other Tools:**

- [Nmap](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ssl-enum-ciphers.html) is great for testing network issues:

  ```
  nmap -sV --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 www.onlinepayment.com.my
  ```
- The [Qualys SSL Scanner](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html) can be used to review the quality and security of the connection. You can compare the results to [Mozilla's recommended server configs](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS) if you're really zealous.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to hit that site from my machine and my firewall blocked it. I am not sure why you want to go to that site but I would make sure that you know what you are doing as it doesn't hit me as a site I would want to go to. :)

Can you ping the IPaddress?

It resolves to IP Address = 202.76.234.124
      Service Provider   = GTC MY PIP NET
      Domain Name        = GLOBALTRANSIT.NET
      ASN Number         = 
      ASN Name           = 
      Network Speed      = DSL
      Country CC         = MY
      Country            = MALAYSIA
      Region             = KUALA LUMPUR
      City               = KUALA LUMPUR
      Longitude          = 101.686531066895
      Latitude           = 3.14120006561279
      Zipcode            = -
      TimeZone           = +08:00
      BestAnswer         = 0

Comment: Yup, we know the company hosting that site. It's a registered payment gateway actually hehe.
No worries there.

But interestingly you said your firewall blocked it. That could be a clue. Maybe some firewall at my hosting site blocked it as well because it is blacklisted or something.

May I know why your firewall blocked it?

Comment: My firewall blocked it because I block IPs by country and I don't need any access to servers in Malaysia. I did just load it from an Azure VM, Server 2012R2 both IE and Chrome. Worked fine. I think it is a network issue. Can you try on a different network? i.e. use a mifi? A ping didn't work from my Azure VM so they are not responding to pings.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the DNS settings on your server to use Google's DNS server at 8.8.8.8.  You might be using a managed DNS server like OpenDNS that has policies applied to it.